# Having to click "Add Site to Apps" for a Sharepoint Online site in order for the open in explorer feature to work

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, internet-explorer

I am having a heck of time getting Sharepoint libraries to open in explorer consistently.  If I go into a sharepoint library within IE and click the open in explorer button absolutely nothing happens.  Once I click "Tools"-"Add Site to Apps" with IE the library will open in explorer.  I have to do this every time I close the browser.  I have added the site to trusted sites.

What is it about "Add Site to Apps" that allows that open in explorer feature to work?

Answer (score 0):

Not a great answer, but I found the cause and a workaround.

By design when we click on a document library it opens said document library in a separate tab.  For whatever reason that tab opens in a 64bit tab which does NOT support "Open in Explorer".

**The work around is:**

**Right click on document library link and click "Open in new tab"**

*This for whatever reason opens it in a 32bit tab and works as expected.*